# Globally disabled ini_set but Override ini_set for a domain

Tags: ini-set

I have disabled ini_set in PHP. I however want a specific domain to use ini_set. How do I enable ini_set for a specific domain?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can't. If you disable it there's no way from that function.

Maybe you can enable php.ini overrride, and put a individual php.ini to the desired folder to enable it and use set_ini again.

If you're using php as module, you can use .htaccess with `php_flag or php_value` to set desired values or flags.

Example: 
`php_value memory_limit 32M` or `php_flag display_errors 1` (display errors must work with value and flag rule as well)